# Bluetooth headset microphone isn't used as audio input device on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, microphone, blueman

I have the Bluetooth headset DEXP BT-212, which has a microphone. I run Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop, Huawei Matebook D.

First of all I connect the headset to the laptop using Blueman. The result is that the headset is used as output.

When I make a call or record something through a microphone, the microphone of the laptop gets used. I want to use the microphone of the headset as input too.

The "Input" dropdown in Sound Setting shows only the built-in laptop microphone. I don't see the headset's microphone there.

How can I achieve this? Am I missing some drivers or advanced config?
Thanks.

Comment: possibly relevant https://askubuntu.com/a/1280776/527764