# Bluetooth headset HSP/HFP unavailable - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

Yes, it is yet another question about using a bluetooth headset on Linux...
I have seen a lot of similar posts but none with a solution that fixed my problem. Maybe someone can understand what is different in my case.

I have a bluetooth headset Oppo Enco Quiet that I try to use with the HSP/HFP profile for video-calls. When I connect it to my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop it automatically uses the A2DP profile. Using this profile the sound output is fine but I cannot use the microphone (which is normal as this profile is unidirectional). When I try to switch it to HSP/HFP with Pavu control, the option is showed but unavailable and it does not change the profile. Trying to change it with Blueman gives me an error (`Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit`).

I tried a bunch of things found over the internet without luck. **The weird thing is that a couple of hours after having unsuccessfully tried to solve this, I made a new attempt to switch the profile and it worked fine.** I could switch the profile from A2DP to HSP/HFP and use the microphone (and switch it back to A2DP without problem). The audio output was not as good as with A2DP but at least I could use my headset for a video call. Unfortunately, after rebooting, I am stuck again in my previous situation with HSP/HFP unavailable...

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280768/mono-only-blurtooth-headset look at the answer of this question it was the only solution I found.

Comment: @David I just tried to remove the device from my bluetooth devices list, reboot and then reconnect. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1339908/1318153 is working for my case