# Using Sony WH-1000XM3 as output AND input headset under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones, codecs

I need to use the Sony WH-1000XM3 bluetooth headset as output and input device for web calls / webinars (mostly zoom). Currently I manage to use it as output device with the "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)" configuration. My understanding is that I need to get "aptX/LDAC" running for example with installing this: ppa:berglh/pulseaudio-a2dp. I spent hours searching the answer in this forum and in other places and tried different solutions. So far the only effect was that I couldn't even use the headphones as output device any longer.
Amongst the things I tried:

- installing "ppa:berglh/pulseaudio-a2dp"; https://github.com/EHfive/pulseaudio-modules-bt/wiki/Packages#ubuntu
- re-installing pulseaudio / pulseaudio-module-bluetooth and pavucontrol as suggested here: [Ubuntu 20.04 no sound out of Bluetooth headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232159/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound-out-of-bluetooth-headphones)
- Option # 3: of the previous link: removing old config of pulse and reboot
- re-installing blueman

When I open the bluetooth devices manager (after installing the ppa mentioned above) and right-click on the WH-1000XM3 device and go to "Audio Profile" it shows me a selection of seven options: "headset_head_unit (HSP/HFP)", "High Fidelity Playback (A2Dp Sink: -a2dp_sink_sbc / -a2dp_sink_aac / -a2dp_sink_aptx / -a2dp_sink_aptx_hd / -a2dp_sink_ldac" or "Off". Whatever audio profile I choose it always results in the following error: "Failed to change profile to a2dp_sink_ldac"

So far my conclusion is that it is impossible to use the Sony WH-1000XM3 under Ubuntu 20.04. Is there any option left / something I haven't tried to fix this issue?

Regards
K

Comment: This profile does not work?

Comment: Which profile are you referring to? After re-installing pulseaudio (sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth) and rebooting, the profile/configuration that I can choose (in the Sound Settings / pavucontrol) is "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)" without _LDAC or _aptx etc. at the end. With this profile I can use my headphones as output device but not as input device. Or I install from the ppa mentioned the codecs, then nothing works at all. It offers me to choose from the LDAC/APTX/AAC codecs (in the bluetooth devices manager) but when I choose an error occurs.

Comment: (HSP/HFP) oops I guess I forgot to paste. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, I am happy about every hint. When I change the configuration in the sound settings to "Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)" the "Output Device" get set back to "Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller" and as "Input Device" I can choose the WH-100XM3 Headset, but when I close the settings and open them again the drop down for "Input Device" is empty again, so it is not really selected. Similar in "pavucontrol": I can choose HSP/HFP in configuration but "Input Devices" is still empty ("No input devices available").

Comment: I had the same problem here is the answer I got https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280768/mono-only-blurtooth-headset it is quite a long answer

Comment: There is a long thread (and not a little controversy) but a patch in the pipeline for Pulseaudio to support higher-fidelity inputs over BT : https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/merge_requests/440  : Input works for me via the HSP/HFP profile, but sounds terrible. Presently I am instead using the digital input in my webcam for input, and the high fidelity output to listen, which is not ideal but better than sounding like you're in a bathtub by a busy freeway.