Sony headphones connected by bluetooth as "headset" does not read input, but has low audio quality when connected as "handsfree"
I am trying to get my Sony WH-CH720N headphones to cooperate over Bluetooth with Linux (Ubuntu 24.04) but I am having the following trouble.
If I select the output device as "Headset", I get good sound quality, but the microphone is not used. Instead, my built-in laptop microphone is used.
A "Handsfree" microphone device seems to be available, but if I select it, the output device is switched to "Handsfree" as well. This makes the audio quality suffer greatly, as if it were sent through a phone call or something.
I attach a composite screenshot of the settings pages for the "Headset" and "Handsfree" options.
Changing the "Configuration" setting with "Headset" makes no difference.
Changing the "Configuration" setting with "Handsfree" is synchronised between the output and input device, and selecting the first option is not possible for some reason. Notably, the two configurations do sound different, in that one seems to allow more treble, while the other seems to allow more bass, but they're both terrible anyways.

Nota bene I had similar trouble over on Windows. On that system, the headset always sounded bad (i.e. there was no way for me to switch over to an equivalent of the no-mic "Headset" option), until I followed this guide to switch off a "Handsfree telephony" service.

Sorry that is how it works. If the microphone is active the sound quality is reduced. When you switch you are changing profiles. One profile gives better sound no mic and one gives mic and sound. BTW this has been addressed many times on this site.

See this existing question for more details. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280768/bluetooth-headset-only-plays-sound-in-mono

I went ahead and rechecked my solution on Windows. I would love to say that you are obviously wrong since I got it to work on Windows, but I made a diagnostic mistake and I admit it doesn't fully work there. However, here's the important part. While you are right about sound quality being reduced, on Windows it loses a bit of depth. It pretty much just goes from stereo to mono. But on Ubuntu it feels like it is being sent through a phone call. And that problem I was able to fix on Windows.

OK, see, that's the point. This is not just mono, as mentioned in the linked question. It legitimately sounds bad.

You could trying booting from a live media of Ubuntu 22.04 and see if it is the same there.

Thanks for the link though, it provided me with some much needed context (doesn't solve anything though). I could try booting from a live USB. I might try and I'll get back to you.

Actually, nevermind, I did even more digging around in Windows and I think that ultimately I didn't achieve anything on that system either. It turns out that Windows is very clever and switches between various profiles depending on what is being used, so it was slightly challenging to confirm (or in this case: disprove) everything.

Could you upvote and or accept my answer?

As @David kindly pointed out, what I wanted to achieve was impossible.
I thought it was possible, because I believed I achieved it on Windows, but that OS was being very clever and made it hard for me to properly diagnose everything.

Sorry that is how it works.
If the microphone is active the sound quality is reduced. When you switch you are changing profiles. One profile gives better sound no mic and one gives mic and sound.
This link is more in depth but basically says the same thing.
Bluetooth headset only plays sound in mono
As the OP in this case points out he found that the sound from the Sony just does not give good sound and he feels is less then mono. Some headphones may simply not work well in the mic on profile.
